# Array/Object strange behavior

Tags: javascript, ios

Following Javascript:

**WORKING**

```
            //Going to set on local storage on an iPhone
            window.localStorage.setItem("emailaddress", "test@test.de");
            //Loading local storage
            var storage = window.localStorage.getItem("emailaddress");
            alert(storage); //test@test.de 
            var servicename = "test";
            window.plugins.keychain.getForKey(storage, servicename);
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
            //Going to set on local storage on an iPhone
            window.localStorage.setItem("emailaddress", "test@test.de" + ":1");
            //Loading local storage
            var storage = window.localStorage.getItem("emailaddress");
            var array = new Array();
            var array = storage.split(":");
            var emailaddress = array[0];
            alert(emailaddress); //test@test.de
            var servicename = "test";
            window.plugins.keychain.getForKey(emailaddress, servicename);
```

Why? Actually I need the second one because I want to store more than with the emailaddress, e.g emailaddress/state/timestamp....

Comment: If you want to store structured data in a single key, consider using JSON instead of inventing your own serialization.

Comment: You say it's not working.  What's not working?  Meaning, are you getting errors, no behavior, etc.?

Comment: I can see no reason why your second example would behave any differently from your first. Is this your actual code?

Comment: window.plugins.keychain.getForKey(emailaddress, servicename); it will not execute at all.

Comment: Me either! YES this is the code!

Comment: FYI: This assignment is not needed `var array = new Array();`. JavaScript variables are dynamically and loosely typed,.